# Find and replace cells value with Datatables plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

i'm looking to find and replace specific values from a known column with the plugin called Datatables.

Here is my code to do that :

```
table.columns(5).search('valuetochange').cells().every( function () {
  this.data('newvalue');
});
```

But it is not working, I also tried other solutions but I didn't find a way to update the cells.

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have not used search method but alternatively this will definitely work

```
table.column(5).nodes().each(function (node, index, dt) {
  if(table.cell(node).data() == valuetochange){
    table.cell(node).data('100');
  }
});
```

Here is a demo **[JsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhirajbodicherla/189Lp6u6/12/)**

Comment: is it possible to change the character in a table eg tiger (new) as tiger new