# Datatables: can you use each() inside an event listener?

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a Datatable where I need to do two things:

- Sum all the figures in a column.
- Find out if the cells in another column have a certain value and, if so, blank them. (Reason: a MySQL table that has a default date of "1970-01-01" if you don't insert the date. I want to replace all the "1970-01-01" instances with an empty cell).

To do that, I attached an event listener to the draw event, and then:

- For 1) I used the sum() Datatables plugin.
- For 2), I followed this answer: [Find and replace cells value with Datatables plugin](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30938127/find-and-replace-cells-value-with-datatables-plugin), and used each().

  ```
  var tabla=$('#list').DataTable();
  tabla.on('draw.dt', function() {
          var bla=tabla.column(10).data().sum();
          tabla.column(9).nodes.each(function(node, index, dt) {
              var ble=tabla.cell(node).data();
              if (/^1970-01-01/.test(ble)) {
                  table.cell(node).data('');
                  }
              });
          });
  ```

The problem is that, when I execute this, I get a **"tabla.column(...).nodes.each is not a function"**. Searching around, I find that this error is caused most of the times when jQuery or the datatable haven't been initialized yet... but in my case, they have most certainly been, because the first thing (the sum()) does get done; in other words, the "bla" variable does get calculated.

This makes me wonder whether you can use each() inside an event trigger; otherwise, what could be causing this?

Answer (score 1):

You could use the [$.each](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.each/) function to iterate over an arbitrary collection

However, and though I'm not sure what's your intention regarding the sum of the column, I'd recommend working with the [`render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render) option for each column involved.

For instance, in the case of the date column you could have a render function like this:

```
render: function (data,type,fullRow){
    if(data === '1970-01-01') {
        return null;
    }
    else {
        return data;
    }
}
```

(Disclaimer: not tested!)

The `drawCallback` function (and the draw event, for that matter ) gets called every single time Datatables need to redraw the table: initial loading, filtering, sorting, new row added, etc. This might have some unforeseen collateral effects, or simply an impact in performance.
Hope it helps you!

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Correct me if I'm wrong, though: you can't set the "render()" function at runtime, only at initialization, right? My problem is that I'm working with a Datatable set up by an web app, and I'd rather not touch its source code; in other words, I can't modify the code that initializes the datatable. I can only attach event listeners to it after it's been created.

Comment: Oh I see!, in that case you're stuck with events, I guess. You could try using the `init` event, which fires once the table is initialized [Here](https://datatables.net/reference/event/) is the complete list of events you can work with. By the way, according to [the docs](https://datatables.net/manual/events#Listening-for-events), the '.dt' namespace shouldn't be necessary in your example